# Is it possible to use inversify to route a task?

Tags: javascript, typescript, inversifyjs

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to use inverisfy as a sort of factory for task handlers .

Let's say I have a task coming in from some sort of queueing system. The task is just json, and it has a property "type" that is a string, and lines up with some sort of handler that I tag in my code. The task is coming in through a HTTP POST command.

I'd like to use inversify tags and a single task handler controller method to handle the task, using the container to try and find a task handler that is tagged to handle the specific task type being delivered, instantiate the handler, and handle the task. Alternately I could code this myself with some sort of factory, or even build my own decorator, but this seems like something inversify should be able to handle.

Specifically, I'm hoping there's a way to register on the class itself that it can handle a certain type of task. Something like:

```
@injectable()
@tagged("task.getBalance")
export class BalanceHandler implments TaskHandler {}
```

It seems like maybe I can do this during container binding, but that's not ideal because every time I add the ability to handle a task to a class, I need to remember to go back to the container to register it.

Thanks!